# glassfish hosting on Amazon EC2 cloud

Tags: glassfish, amazon-ec2, glassfish-3

I've had a look at the Amazon EC2 and it looks like an extremely comprehensive
service, but I'm struggling to find any up to date instructions for how to
build an AMI with Glassfish + MySQL. I have found a few fairly rough notes
that are a couple of years old, but this raises a few questions:

1. Why doesn't Amazon or Oracle provide a ready built AMI? It looks like SUN
   did produce an AMI several years ago, but I'll want to use g/f 3.1.
2. Should I be reading anything into this apparent lack of recent activity,
   are there any problems with EC2+Glassfish?
3. Has anyone tried using glassfish 3.1 clustering on ec2?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the community AMIs? There seems to be at least one with MySQL and Glassfish 3.0, and several with Glassfish 3.1

Comment: Are you married to using Glassfish? I have a hard time believing it is a strategic product for Oracle and might not get the same type of attention as say Weblogic would.

Comment: Yes, I spent hours going through the list yesterday trying to find an appropriate AMI. When I search the AMIs for 'glassfish' I get 5 results, the latest glassfish version being 2.1. I need 3.1, not 3.0. As for being married to glassfish, I've been developing on this platform for 2 years and don't need the hassle of moving to a new environment. I agree with you though, I don't think that glassfish and JSF are in good hands at the corporate level. Bring back SUN Microsystems!

Comment: I can't reproduce this - if I go to the AWS management console (Region: US East) -> Launch instance -> Community AMIs -> All -> Enter search term: "glassfish", I get several hits, glassfish 3.1 and 3.0 among them. Are you using another AWS region?

Answer (score 2):

I teach this in my blog, it's in portugues, but has lots of images that can help you and you can translate it with Google Translator plugin in Google Chrome, if even with this tutorial you cannot do this, give me a call then I try to help you out, okay ?

http://legionti.blogspot.com.br/2011/08/como-instalar-glassfish-3-no-amazon-ec2.html

Answer (score 1):

If there is no good solution for GF clustering on ec2, then you definitely should take a look at the Jelastic [GlassFish Auto-Clustering](https://blog.jelastic.com/2017/11/02/glassfish-payara-auto-clustering-cloud-hosting/) package.